# defining POST variable as href link, target='blank'

Tags: php, html

I am trying to edit this code to make it a link which opens ins a new tab, but wherever I insert the "target='blank'" part in the code I get a parse error, can anyone one help me out please. Thanks.

```
$websiteurl = "<a href=\"" . $_POST['websiteurl'] . "\">" . $_POST['websiteurl'] . "</a>";
```

need to add:

```
target='blank'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$websiteurl = '<a target="_blank" href="' . 
      $_POST['websiteurl'] . '">' . $_POST['websiteurl'] . '</a>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed `_`.

put `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 2):

Mine is like this:

```
$output .= "<p class='fb-page-name'><a href='". $app['link'] ."' title='". $app['name'] ."'>". $app['name'] ."</a></p>\n";
```

I had to use `target='_blank'` instead of `target="_blank"`.

I'm just saying because maybe someone is struggling with it as I was.

Answer (score 0):

```
$websiteurl = '<a href="' . $_POST['websiteurl'] . '" target="_blank">' . $_POST['websiteurl'] . '</a>';
```